# Can't format my array properly following query

Tags: php, mysql

I keep getting this:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [thread_id] => 136
                [owner_id] => 1
                [subject] => asdhjkasdh
                [body] => askjdhaksjd
                [timestamp] => 2012-03-22 22:03:51
                [slug] => asdhjkasdh
            )

    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [thread_id] => 137
                [owner_id] => 1
                [subject] => asdhjkasdh
                [body] => askjdhaksjd
                [timestamp] => 2012-03-22 22:03:56
                [slug] => asdhjkasdh
            )

    )
```

But I need each [0] and [1] to contain the data, not another array.

Here is my code: The initial query returns the thread_id in array form.  I then use the thread_id to pull the info from the thread table.  Though I can't seem to organize it correctly in the array.

```
            $query = $this->db->query($sql);
            $result = $query->result_array();
            $thread = array();
            foreach ($result as $thread_id)
            {
                $id = $thread_id['thread_id'];
                $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM thread WHERE thread_id='$id'");
                array_push($thread, $query->result_array());
            }
            print_r($thread);
            return $thread;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Not related to the question, but you should be using a SQL join instead of nested PHP loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your database object is returning a multi-dimensional array which is being pushed to your $thread array.
Instead of

```
array_push($thread, $query->result_array());
```

try

```
$thisRow = $query->result_array();
array_push($thread, $thisRow[0] );
```

Also it looks like you are running one query, looping through the results and then running another query. This isn't usually a very efficient way of retrieving the data and can usually be refactored using a JOIN. Maybe post your separate queries as a new question so we can help you improve that.

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_merge` instead of `array_push` then

Answer (score 0):

It is because `$query->result_array()` will give you an array, even if it has only 1 row in it.
After that you push that array into your array ($thread).

If you are sure you will always get one row, you can better use

```
$row = $query->row();
```

Maybe add  `LIMIT 1` to your query to be sure ;)

You can also do

```
$thread[] = $query->row();
```